# @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) annotation but getting request body as string

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I am currently working on a project which was maintained by some other team and now i need to maintain it. While i was going through the project i found some thing below:

In `jax-rs` controller it was annotated by `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` but the method takes request body as **`String`** **rather than JSON**. Then what is the use of the annotation? Does it help in content negotiation anyway?

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createCake(final String requestBody){.......}
```

**How it is converting a JSON body to string?**

My technology stack if it anyway helps to answer:

JAX-RS
Spring 3.2
Jersey 2.4

Comment: `method takes request body as String rather than JSON` What would it mean for it to take JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@Consumes` serves the following purpose. It restricts the mapping for your handlers. For example, you may have two handlers for the path `/resource`, one mapped to consume XML and the other mapped to consume json. The dispatcher will choose the right one based on the request's content-type.

The parameter type can be anything as long as there is an appropriate converter for the specified media type to the parameter type itself. In this case, there's very likely a converter from any media type to `String`.

Comment: I have not specified any thing. then how come it is converting to String?

Comment: @Trying Converting it to String as opposed to what? (Jersey comes with a bunch of default converters. You can probably configure it with others.)

Comment: That means you are telling me that Jersey default converting the JSON to String as i have not registered any converter like jackson. Am i correct?

Comment: @Trying JSON is a format for text. It is not a data type. The request body contains bytes. Jersey will read those bytes and construct a String.